# Не работает слайдер JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, вообщем практикуюсь на JavaScript, дело дошло до слайдера, и тут заминка. Делаю вот такой вот контейнер:

```
<section class="first_sect">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="img_box">
            <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="google.com" class="opas">
            <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="google.com" >
            <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="google.com" >
            <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="google.com" >
            <img src="img/img6.jpg" alt="google.com" >
            <img src="img/img5.jpg" alt="google.com" >
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Применяю следующее `css` правило:

```
.img_box > img {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Делаю  класс c `opacity:1` для первого потомка `img`, далее через `js` через итерацию и newclass меняю класс у последующих элементов.

```
Собственно вопрос, почему приоритет для

.img_box > img {
    opacity : 0; 
}
```

Выше чем класс

```
.opas {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

И при переборе классов, `opacity` остается неизменным.

P.S решил проблему задав свойство опасисти, через класс

```
.slider img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Вообщем, спасибо за ответы, извините если вопрос нубовский. Только учюсь. Успехов Вам!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш вопрос мало касается `js`.
Но в целом: вся штука в том, что селектор `.img_box > img` более спецефичен, чем просто селектор по классу, из-за этого стили не применяются. Аналогичный эффект вы можете получить, если сделаете так:

```
.img_box img {
    opacity : 0; 
}
```

И перебивать его с помощью такого селектора:

```
.img_box .opas {
    opacity : 1; 
}
```

Так должно сработать как вы хотите

**UPD**
Про специфичность селекторов, да и в целом неплохая теория по `html`, `css` есть на [Этом ресурсе](https://htmlacademy.ru/program)

Конкретно про специфичность селекторов и их вес:
[Хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/47910/)
[Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не подскажите где можно почитать про это?

Comment: @ВладиславДидковский Есть несколько хороших ресурсов, сейчас дополню ответ. Если решение вам подошло - приймите, пожалуйста, мой ответ.

Comment: @ВладиславДидковский Дополнил ответ, добавил туда несколько полезных ссылок

Comment: Хороший материал, сделал так .opas {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

Comment: @ВладиславДидковский По возможности - не делайте так. Это не очень хороший путь решения вашего вопроса.